# ArcGIS Spatial Statistics: Distance to 3rd/4th/5th closest feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, spatial-statistics

We have an algorithm which requires us to produce a score based on the distance from any given cell in an output raster to a score calculated from the distances of the 3rd closest, 4th closest, and 5th closest point features in a separate feature class.

For example, our score might be calculated as score=a/(3c+4d+5e), where a is a constant and c, d, and e are the (Euclidean) distances to the 3rd closest, 4th closest, and 5th closest points on the input feature class, respectively.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to write a custom function to calculate such a cell statistic?

I have looked at the various [Proximity Analysis](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/java/Gp_ToolRef/geoprocessing/proximity_analysis.htm) functions, but they all seem to leave no room for defining custom scoring metrics.

Comment: Choosing an effective solution depends on (a) the number of cells in the raster and (b) the number of point features. What can you tell us about these quantities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shall caveat this answer by stating I don't work with raster very often, so there might be a better way. That being said, my method of accomplishing this task would be to first convert the input raster to points. With these points you can perform a `PointDistance_analysis` to determine distances between the two point feature classes (raster and input). You can then create a list of all these distances per raster point, sort the list, and then calculate and add your weighted value to a field in your points through an `UpdateCursor`. Once you have this value assigned to each point, you can then convert your point feature class back to a raster.

Due to the number of points converted from a raster, I am sure that the `PointDistance_analysis` will be slow.

Try something like this (I would be surprised if there weren't any typos, however):

```
from arcpy import *
import os

inRaster = "Raster\full\path"

pointFC = "Point\feature\class\full\path"

Outworkspace = r"C:\GISStuff"
TempTableName = "TempTable.dbf"

#Raster to point
outPoint = r"in_memory\outpoint"
RasterToPoint_conversion (inRaster, outPoint)

#Point Distance analysis
outTable = os.path.join (Outworkspace, TempTableName) 
PointDistance_analysis (outPoint, pointFC, outTable)

#Create empty dictionary
di = {}

#Iterate through point distance table
cursor = da.SearchCursor (outTable, ["INPUT_FID", "DISTANCE"])
for row in cursor:
    #Check if Input FID is a key in dictionary
    if row[0] in di:
        #If yes, append distance to list
        di[row[0]].append (row[1])
    else:
        #If no, assign distance as list to dictionary
        di[row[0]] = [row[1]]
del cursor

#Add Weighted value field to outpoint
AddField_management (outPoint, "SCORE", "DOUBLE")

#Iterate through points
cursor = da.InsertCursor (outPoint, ["SCORE", "OID@"])
for row in cursor:
    #Get list of distances for OID
    distList = di[row[1]]
    #Sort List
    sortedDistList = sorted (distList)
    #Get distances
    Dist1 = sortedDistList[0]
    Dist2 = sortedDistList[1]
    Dist3 = sortedDistList[2]
    Dist4 = sortedDistList[3]
    Dist5 = sortedDistList[4]

    #Do math

    Value = 7 + (3 * Dist1) + (4 * Dist2) #Use your equation

    #Update row
    row[0] = Value
    cursor.updateRow (row)

del cursor

#Point to raster
outRaster = r"New\out\raster\full\path"
PointToRaster_conversion (outPoint, "SCORE", outRaster, {cell_assignment}, {priority_field}, {cellsize})
```

Comment: This is untenable for large rasters.